# Resize text to fit the text into label - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to automatically change the size of font depends on the length of text that fit into fixed size of label in vb.net

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this event for Label.Paint

```
Private Sub Label1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Label1.Paint
    Dim ratio = Label1.Width / Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(Label1.Text, Label1.Font).Width
    Dim newWidth = Math.Floor(Label1.Font.Size * ratio)
    Label1.Font = New Font(Label1.Font.FontFamily, CInt(newWidth))
End Sub
```

It measures the text and resizes it to fit the Label. This will be called when the label is drawn - when the text is changed, label resized, shown, etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]